# VBA code to unprotect a opened powerpoint presentation, then protect it again before saving it?

Tags: vba, powerpoint, password-protection, presentation

I protected a power point presentation from user modifying it. However I can't use VBA to un-protect it.

I tried to use this code below but it doesn't work. It only works for unprotected presentation. But you will have to remove the pw from the code.

```
set p = pa.presentations.open(pth + pptname, pw)
```

Comment: I don't think there's any way to do this via VBA, even from Powerpoint itself.  `presentations.open` doesn't have a parameter which accepts the password.

Comment: How about if the PowerPoint is already open. Kind of like excel. Set j to this presentation then j.password  = pw etc. I tired but presentation object doesn't have password. Just saying or something similar.

Comment: How about do it in PowerPoint VBA and have excel VBA call PowerPoint VBA ?

Comment: "I don't think there's any way to do this via VBA, *even from Powerpoint itself*"  There's no built-in function to do this.  You can find various work-arounds - eg. https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/office/Remove-or-Change-Password-0efd9823

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you know the password, you can open the file with something like:

```
Presentations.Open("c:\temp\protected_presentation.pptx::password::")
```

And set the password on a presentation with eg:

```
ActivePresentation.Password = "Hide_me"
```

[editing to add a complete tested, working example that assumes a presentation C:\temp\testtest.pptx that's been saved with password opensesame]

```
Sub TestTest()

    Dim oPPTApp As Object
    Dim oPPTPres As Object

    Set oPPTApp = CreateObject("PowerPoint.Application")

    If Not oPPTApp Is Nothing Then
        Set oPPTPres = oPPTApp.presentations.Open("C:\temp\test.pptx::opensesame::")
        MsgBox oPPTPres.slides(1).Shapes(1).TextFrame.TextRange.Text
        oPPTPres.Close
        oPPTApp.Quit
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Ok thanks. I am going to give it a try and see if it works. :)

Comment: I tried it and it didn't work.The first code to open when the presentation is password protected, the presentation will ask me for a password before it can go on. The second code just throw an error message "ActiveX component can't create object".

Comment: The first code:  set p = pa.presentations.open(path + pptname + "::pw::"). P is presentation, pa is pptx  application, path is where pptx reside, pptname is presentation name, pw is presentation password.  I get asked to input my password before the code can go on.

Comment: Use & instead of + for string concatenation (don't know if it'll make a difference in this case, but it's basic good practice).  And try doing the concatenation into an intermediate variable then passing the variable to Presentations.Open

Comment: Since you haven't shown us your code as requested, I've added an example to my original reply. If you still won't show the code that's not working and explain exactly WHAT "not working" means and on what line it fails, there's not much anyone can do to help.

Comment: I tried your example and it didn't work. I got error message "Run-time error '-2147024894(80070002)': Method 'Open' of object 'Presentations' failed.

Comment: One more time:  show us the code you currently have and indicate where the error occurs.  If you're not willing to do that, I'm not willing to spend any more time on this.

Comment: Thanks for the message. I am sorry but I deleted all the codes that I tried that didn't work. So right now I really don't have any code to show you, only the examples you provided that I tried but didn't work (I posted up - scroll up, you will see) and I have shown you the error message. It is located at this code -  Set pR = pA.presentations.open("C:\d\file.ppxt::pe::") and error message is - "Run-time error '-2147024894(80070002)': Method 'Open' of object 'Presentations' failed: