# Is there a way to open a PowerPoint file with write password as Read-Only with VBA, in the same way as with Word Documents?

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I want to open a PowerPoint Presentation that has a write password, directly with VBA without showing the dialog box, which asks to enter the password or open as Read-Only.

I can do this in a Word document with the following code:

```
Sub openWriteProtectedWord()
    Documents.Open FileName:="C:\Users\user\Desktop\Doc2.docx", ReadOnly:=True
End Sub
```

When this is executed the file opens automatically without showing the pop-up where I have to click Read-Only button.

The code for PowerPoint:

```
Sub openWriteProtected()
    Presentations.Open FileName:="C:\Users\user\Desktop\test.pptx", ReadOnly:=msoTrue
End Sub
```

When the code is executed the pop-up dialog shows up to enter password or open as read-only.
Is this a missing feature for PowerPoint, or it is done in another way?

Comment: Hmmm - according to the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/powerpoint.presentations.open), that looks like the way you should open as read only.

Comment: Yeah, I read and re-read the docs, but it is not working in the same way as with Word documents.  According to docs, the Open method for Documents object is different from that of Presentations object, since it doesn't even have the option to automatically enter the password.

Comment: Please see Steve Rindsberg's answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45267951/vba-code-to-unprotect-a-opened-powerpoint-presentation-then-protect-it-again-be

Comment: @JohnKorchok thank you for your suggestion, but that solution works only for Password property of Presentation, not WritePassword. Also, I don't want to enter the password, I want to open it as Read-Only directly, without showing the dialog box that asks to enter the password or open as read-only.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I don't see any way of avoiding that dialog. Even SendKeys can't get around it.

Comment: @JohnKorchok thank you very much for your efforts. It looks like Microsoft didn't care that much adding this feature to PowerPoint.

Comment: You could, of course, simply set the file's read-only attribute in Windows...

Comment: @macropod thank you for your solution, but the read-only attribute would allow the user to edit and save as.

Comment: True, but that's no different than what cab be done in Word with read-only protection by copying the content and pasting it into another document before saving that,

Comment: @macropod In Powerpoint it works differently. Without the write password you cannot Save or Save As and also cannot copy. Changing the file attribute to Read-only will only disable Save.