# How do I use py32win to automate opening powerpoint files with password?

Tags: python, com, powerpoint, pywin32, win32com

For work, I need to convert all ppt/pptx and doc/docx files in a given folder and convert them to pdf. However, some of the files are password protected. So far I have this code:

```
import os
import win32com
import win32com.client

print("Please set the directory you want to scrape files from:")
FOLDER_PATH = input()


def PPTtoPDF(inputFileName, outputFileName, formatType=32):
    powerpoint = win32com.client.Dispatch("Powerpoint.Application")
    if inputFileName[-3:] == "ppt":
        outputFileName = outputFileName[:-4] + ".pdf"
    if inputFileName[-4:] == "pptx":
        outputFileName = outputFileName[:-5] + ".pdf"
    if (inputFileName[-3:] == "ppt") | (inputFileName[-4:] == "pptx"):
        try:
            deck = powerpoint.Presentations.Open(inputFileName, WithWindow=False)
            deck.SaveAs(outputFileName, formatType)  # formatType = 32 for ppt to pdf
            deck.Close()
            os.remove(inputFileName)
        except:
            print("PPT2PDF: There's an error" + inputFileName)
```

After that I have another function that grabs the filenames from the directory I've set, put it into a list, and then loops through the list to run the PPTtoPDF function.

The above function works, but I have to input the password manually every time there's a password-protected document.

I have tried the following fixes:

```
deck = powerpoint.Presentations.Open(inputFileName, WithWindow=False, Password="password1234")
```

But this turns an error:

```
TypeError: Open() got an unexpected keyword argument 'Password'
```

A similar error also often happens with the WithWindow argument, and I don't know why that is. Sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't.

I have also tried

```
deck = powerpoint.Presentations.Open(inputFileName, False, True, None, "password1234")
```

which was suggested in [How to open a password protected excel file using python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19450837/how-to-open-a-password-protected-excel-file-using-python)
But it returns the following error:

```
TypeError: Open() takes from 1 to 5 positional arguments
```

I'm not sure what went wrong. Coding is definitely not my expertise, and the documentation for py32win seems to be scarce and very technical. Any help/suggestion is appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you had a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45286381/1902513?